# GMOCK - whats the benefit over running my sample code

Tags: c++, googlemock

I just started learning GMOCK - a functionality to test C++ Class Methods. After doing a sample of them I could not understand why we are doing via GMOCK - a round about way / technique to test the methods. I find the GMOCK to only test whether for a given input the code gives desired output.

So would my sample code i.e. writing sample code calling Class methods would do so? I can very well verify the output also to confirm.

Now say the code is in layered architecture and one team owns two layers of ownership. The second layer calls interfaces of third layer belonging to other team. Assume second layer of code is highly volatile for modification related to third layer's API. So each time I touch I completely modify my GMOCK interfaces also.

GCC and other compilers gives options to link and bind defined methods to user defined methods.

Exactly where are we benefiting using GMOCK? I might be missing hence the reason to post my query.

Comment: Gmock allows you to control the behavior of dependencies you're injecting to your code. Say - we in our company have a `pubsub` library. The interface is quite simple - `subscribe, unsubscribe, publish`, and so on.

Comment: Problem is - the real implementation can't run in test environment, so instead we use a mock for that. We then check in our test that the mock was called correctly. f.e: if you expect that your class will subscribe to `MESSAGE-X` in the constructor, you assert the `ASSERT_CALLED(pubsubMock, subscribe('MESSAGE-X'))`. Or that given some input to your method, `publish` will be called with the correct arguments. That's what Mock allows you to do - make sure that your dependencies are used correctly inside your class.

Comment: Take for example - you want to use a random element inside your class. But you can't really test randomness. So you extract the `randomizing` logic to an interface and inject it in your class. In testing, you mock the `Randomizer`, and you control what value will be returned when the `randomValue` will be called. That's just an example.

Comment: I understand your point - but a sample code test cases will also do - in both cases we would need some dummy code injection

Comment: That's really up to the use case. When I had to write a hashtable implementation to a database table, I started it out by mocking, but quickly I realized the doing `EXPECT_CALL(memory, read(0x345asd)).Returns(...)` every time - will neither help me do it quickly, nor test my use case. Instead, I had to create a dummy implementation to my memory reader interface that wrapped my own `char*` that I allocate, allowing me to test my logic. This is really up to the use case.

Comment: Hope I helped you. If there's another question, or perhaps you want me to clarify something, just say so

Comment: The point is to write tests which are independent from it's dependencies.
So you can know that when your tests are broke, it's not because of the dependencies, but because of the class itself.
It also let you test things which otherwise would be really hard or even impossible to test.